# Entity Framework migrations looking for deleted table

Tags: sql, entity-framework

I am using EF6.

I created a migration which had some issues, because SQL had created a index that it knew nothing about.  Trying to manually fix up what EF migrations had generated created more problems than it solved, so I decided to delete the entire table in SQL, then re-scaffold the migration.

The problem is that the new migration expects the table to be there.  I expected migrations to know that it wasn't there, but this is obviously not how it works?  Is that correct?

Is there a way to tell Migrations to look at the current DB and re scaffold from there?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on where you are in development, the easiest thing might be to just delete existing migrations and apply a new baseline using the -IgnoreChanges attribute (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dn579398.aspx#option1).

Otherwise, you can go through the generated Up() code and comment out lines that don't need to be applied. Then do Update-Database and your model will be back in sync.